# Minting Dapp with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web3js, ethers.js, decentralized-applications

As the title suggests I am wondering what the necessary steps are to built a mintin dapp with Wordpress, or understand why it's not possible.

I am glad about any clues that may point me in the right direction.

I am well aware of the ether.js and web3.js libraries but I am not sure if its as simple as putting the plain logic for wallet connect and mint via javascript.

I did not find any usefull plugins that would solve this problem. Also it seems the best practice to built these things in react.js. Is that because of the dependencies?